# How does method look up work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

My understanding is that method look up scans the receiver's class and the methods defined there. If it's not found, it keeps moving the hierarchy chain until it finds it. This fits this case:

```
class A
  def hello
    p 'hello world'
  end
end

A.new.hello
```

where `hello` is defined in `A.new.class`. But it doesn't fit the situation when we call a method on a `Class` object:

```
class A
  def self.hello
    p 'hello world'
  end
end

A.hello
```

This should link `A`'s eigen class with method `hello` -> `Object` --> `BasicObject`.

Ruby finds the method by looking at the receiver's class and then moving up the ladder. It should have looked the method at `A.class` which is `Class`, and never found the method `hello`?

Comment: @sawa What I meant is that it works, but I am not sure why it works. 
The process by which ruby finds method is by looking at the object's class and then finding the method there. 

In my second example, `A` 's class is `Class` and there isn't `hello` method defined there ?

Comment: @yask My apologies. I didn't understand what you were asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is A’s eigenclass is **not** `Class`, but the class derived from `Class`:

```
▶ A.singleton_class
#⇒ #<Class:A>
▶ A.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
#⇒ [:hello]
```

Comment: Ah!! That makes so much sense. Thanks a bunch. :)

Comment: I have another followup question, can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004117/how-class-method-look-ups-work-while-inheritance-in-ruby ?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you fix your program - right now it would just abort with syntax error - to use `class` instead of `Class`, as @sawa already pointed out, the difference between your examples is this:

In the first example, `hello` is defined as an instance method of A, i.e. each object of type A has this method. `A.new` is of type A, so the method is executed. The receiver is the object *A.new*.

In the second example, `hello` is defined as a class method of A, i.e. only the object A itself (A being a class, is of course also an object, because everything is an object) contains the method hellow. If you write `A.hello`, *A* is the receiver.

Comment: `A` is indeed a receiver, but the question was (if I parsed it correctly :) “what class the method is defined on.”