# How does class method look-up work during inheritance in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, class methods are looked up in the singleton class of the receiver object.

```
class Child
  class << self
    def hello
      p 'hello'
    end
  end
end
```

I understand how this works; it's fetched from `Child`'s singleton class.

```
p Child.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
>> [:hello]
```

But when we do inheritance such as in this case,

```
class Parent
  class << self
    def hello
      p 'hello'
    end
  end
end

class Child < Parent
end
```

I don't understand how `Child.hello` works. The class `Child` is linked not to its singleton class, but is linked directly to `Class` object.

```
p Child.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
>> []
```

The `Parent` class is however linked to its singleton class, where `hello` is defined.

```
p Parent.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
>>[:hello]
```

But I don't understand how calling `Child.hello` would look up the method in the singleton class of `Parent`.

This is how I see the objects connected:

```
p Child.class.ancestors   
>> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: `Child.singleton_class.superclass #=> #<Class:Parent>`

Comment: You do realize that `instance_methods(false)` means do not include the inherited methods correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, since this question was upvoted, I’ll leave the correct answer here.

`Child.hello` is defined because `Child`’s eigenclass is derived from `Parent`’s eigenclass:

```
▶ Child.singleton_class.superclass
#⇒ #<Class:Parent>
```

The whole ancestor chain of this eigenclass would be:

```
▶ Child.singleton_class.ancestors
#⇒ [#<Class:Child>, #<Class:Parent>, 
#   #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>,
#   Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

First four ancestors are *eigenclasses* of the respective classes in `Child.ancestors` chain. That is how eigenclasses are built/derived in ruby, making calls like `Child.hello` available.

And, while `:hello` method is not shown directly by `Child.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)`, since it’s defined not on `Child`’s eigenclass, it’s still there, thanks to `Parent`’s eigenclass:

```
▶ Child.singleton_class.instance_methods.detect &:hello.method(:==)
#⇒ :hello
```

Answer (score -3):

After calling `Child.class.ancestors` the output will show you ancestors of the class form which Child is instantialized. Yes, it may look weird and confusing but `Child` is an instance of `Class` class.

If you look at another way of declaring classes in Ruby it may become clearer:

```
Child = Class.new { ... }
```

I guess that's the root of your confusion. You were looking for ancestors in the wrong class.

If you want to see `Child`'s ancestors:

```
Child.ancestors
=> [Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

or

Child.new.class.ancestors
=> [Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

I believe that after pointing that out, the lookup for `.hello` method became clear for you.

Comment: Honestly, the lookup for the `.hello` method was crystal clear to me _unless_ I have read the above. Now I am confused :) `Child.ancestors` have _literally nothing_ to do with `.hello`. `Child.singlenton_class.ancestors` do. Downvoted.

Comment: Child.new.class.ancestors's chain is valid for the look up of method of instance of class `Child` ,but not for class `Child`.

Comment: @yask note the method call to `class` in the chain you posted and then consider your comment. While I am not a fan of this answer your comment is even more so wrong.

Comment: Care to explain how is it wrong? The eigen class is added in the object chain, but not shown by `ancestors` method. This might be confusing, but it isn't wrong.

Answer (score -5):

Ruby is not only looking up methods in the singleton class.

Here is a primer on inheritance and method lookup in Ruby: https://gist.github.com/damien-roche/351bf4e7991449714533

Comment: It's looking up methods in the singleton class. The link you posted says the same thing aswell.

Comment: If you read my answer more closely, you'll see that I wrote "Ruby is *not only* looking up methods in the singleton class".

Comment: Ah! sorry. Missed *only* :P

Comment: Pure links are not welcome on SO. This might make a good comment, but it’s not an answer by any mean.